# Error: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance for view function

Tags: solidity, remix, solidity-0.8.x

**I am doing this is Remix**

This is my solidity contract. I just have 3 interfaces which are being used to call methods from 3 different contracts.

The ITaco and IDoodle methods work fine and call without any errors.
However when calling **.tokensOfOwner(address owner) of IPixelTaco** I get the error

"The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance"

This is the contract I am writing:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Address.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

interface ITaco {
    function walletOfOwner(address owner) external view returns (uint256[] memory);
}

interface IDoodle {
    function walletOfOwner(address owner) external view returns (uint256[] memory);
}

interface IPixelTaco {
    function totalSupply() external view returns(uint256);
    function tokensOfOwner(address owner) external view returns(uint256[] memory);
}

contract TacoStaking {
    ITaco public taco;
    IDoodle public doodle;
    IPixelTaco public pt;

    constructor(){
        taco = ITaco(0x47faE0155F418F7355b1ca8e46589811C272a7a8);
        doodle = IDoodle(0x0c0c19675311323eBB19C44318CE00d53Ff65982);
        pt = IPixelTaco(0x577eFe0525c83D2Bf2f8e9EfB1e41bA3FcB84c86);
    }

    function balanceTaco(address owner) external view returns (uint256[] memory) {
        return taco.walletOfOwner(owner);
    }

    function balanceDoodle(address owner) external view returns (uint256[] memory) {
        return doodle.walletOfOwner(owner);
    }

    function balancePT(address owner) external view returns(uint256[] memory){
        return pt.tokensOfOwner(owner);
    }
}
```

For reference this is the method declared in the contract PixelTaco:

```
function tokensOfOwner(address owner) external view override returns (uint256[] memory) {
        unchecked {
            uint256 tokenIdsIdx;
            address currOwnershipAddr;
            uint256 tokenIdsLength = balanceOf(owner);
            uint256[] memory tokenIds = new uint256[](tokenIdsLength);
            TokenOwnership memory ownership;
            for (uint256 i = _startTokenId(); tokenIdsIdx != tokenIdsLength; ++i) {
                ownership = _ownerships[i];
                if (ownership.burned) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (ownership.addr != address(0)) {
                    currOwnershipAddr = ownership.addr;
                }
                if (currOwnershipAddr == owner) {
                    tokenIds[tokenIdsIdx++] = i;
                }
            }
            return tokenIds;
        }
    }
```

Funny thing, the method works fine when calling from PolygonScan
https://polygonscan.com/address/0x577eFe0525c83D2Bf2f8e9EfB1e41bA3FcB84c86#readContract#F12

Query with my wallet: 0xc67Aa95B4AD61b6435d10567EC192e125aF7A0a0